# How to use Wireless Network in Virtualbox?

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, virtualbox, kali-linux

I'm trying to enable Wireless on VirtualBox in my Ubuntu 14.04. I use a Kali Linux as the guest OS, but this OS not show the wi-fi when I connect it.

[image: here]

After starting the guest OS, it still does not show the wi-fi

[image: here]

I already tried the suggestions from [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/282018/wifi-card-on-an-virtualboxs-ubuntu) and [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/282018/wifi-card-on-an-virtualboxs-ubuntu), but my virtualbox does not enable my wireless.

Comment: You won't be able to. It's an unsupported feature.
Check [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134999/wireless-connection-not-figuring-in-vmware-workstation-10kali-linux) thread.

Comment: This works perfectly for me [YouTube: Connect USB Wireless Adapter to Kali Linux in Virtualbox](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K1ETBeRQBs4)

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using an USB filter, just connect the wireless network on the **host** operating system, and define a bridged or NAT connection in the VM configuration.

[image]

On the image referenced in the comments, you have both a bridged adapter to wlan1 *and* an USB filter.

According to the VirtualBox manual, section [3.10](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#idp50164016): "VirtualBox can allow virtual machines to access the USB devices on your host directly. To achieve this, VirtualBox presents the guest operating system with a virtual USB controller. **As soon as the guest system starts using a USB device, it will appear as unavailable on the host.**".

So, if the USB filter is pointing to the WLAN adapter, it will disappear from the host OS when you boot the VM, also disabling the bridged adapter. In that case, remove the USB filter from the configuration.

Comment: Do not work if I make what did you say. See the pic http://oi60.tinypic.com/raokcn.jpg And my notebook brake. I already make this before, but do not fix it.

Comment: Sorry but I already tried what you said here http://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/captura_de_tela_de_2014-07-28_22_18_07-png I disable USB and use just bridged adapter to wlan1, but not appear wireless connection in my debian or Kali see here http://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/captura_de_tela_de_2014-07-28_22_33_17-png