# Kali linux monitor mode

Tags: kali-linux, virtual-machine, monitoring

I'm new to Kali Linux, in theory my laptop suports wifi monitor mode (Microsoft Network 3.4) but when i installed kali linux (pre-built) on VirtualBox and went through the options it was not showing the wireless interface `iwconfig`, while investigating i saw a post saying that in a Virtual Machine i need a USB Wifi adapter. My question here is, do i really need a USB wifi adapter if my laptop already supports monitor mode? or can i just boot kali linux and get my laptop wirless working without a Virtual Machine?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Wireless Network in Virtualbox?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147075/how-to-use-wireless-network-in-virtualbox)

Comment: Please read [Should I use Kali?](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/). Kali is not designed to be used as an operating system, and it is aimed at _expert_ users. If you are learning, that is great, but it means you shouldn't be using Kali. For one thing, Kali ships with networking disabled by default. If you want to learn, use any other Linux: all of them can do anything you can do on Kali, you just need to install the relevant program, so using them to learn will make your life much easier.

Answer (score 1):

By "Microsoft Network 3.4", I assume you mean *Microsoft Network **Monitor** 3.4*? That is Windows-based protocol analyzer software, basically a Microsoft-built competitor for Wireshark. If a Windows driver for a WiFi adapter supports the use of monitor mode in Windows, then Microsoft Network Manager can use it - but Kali and Microsoft Network Monitor have nothing to do with each other. Also, the presence of Microsoft Network Monitor does not necessarily mean your laptop's built-in WiFi chip supports monitor mode.

*WiFi monitor mode* is a WiFi adapter feature that allows the monitoring of low-level WiFi protocol packets that handle WiFi-specific things like network association and WPA encryption. Normally these are handled exclusively by the WiFi adapter hardware/firmware, and apart from a WiFi-specific configuration programming interface, the WiFi adapter looks essentially similar to a wired Ethernet adapter for most regular software.

In order to use WiFi-specific features like monitor mode in a virtual machine, the host operating system needs to completely turn over control of the WiFi adapter to the VM, because there is no standard way for the host and VM to share control of WiFi features like that.

VirtualBox allows turning over USB devices to the VM's control, but cannot do the same for PCIe devices. This is why you'll need a USB WiFi adapter with monitor mode support if you want to use Kali's WiFi tools in a VirtualBox VM (or in any other virtualization environment I know, for that matter).

If you install Kali natively (either dual-booting or as an only OS), then the question of transferring the WiFi adapter control becomes moot, as Kali will be the only running OS at the time and will have direct hardware access. Then it's just a matter of whether or not your laptop's WiFi hardware/firmware supports monitor mode and whether or not the developer of the Linux WiFi adapter driver has managed to make use of that feature.

Because you have not told us any identifying information about your laptop model nor its built-in WiFi chip, it is impossible for us to say anything about whether it would support monitor mode in Kali or not.

Comment: Note that Kali [ships with networking disabled](https://www.kali.org/docs/policy/kali-linux-network-service-policy/), so even though I'm sure everything you write here is correct, it probably _still_ wouldn't help the OP.