# Network setup of KVM hypervisor?

Tags: kvm

I would like to install a KVM type-1 hypervisor. This hypervisor should run two guest operating-systems. Both guest operating-systems need one IPv4 address from 192.168.11.0/24 network and I guess that I should configure one IPv4 address to hypervisor itself for management purposes? I am familiar with bridges under Linux and VLAN-subinterfaces, but what is the recommended practice for such KVM installation, i.e. which interfaces should I create in hypervisor and which interfaces should I create for virtual-machines with *virt-install* and how should I configure management for hypervisor itself?

Comment: What are the options you want to compare? The mail point is IMHO whether the VMs shall be able to (a) communicate with each other and (b) to communicate with the outside world without routing on the hypervisor.

Comment: I am not sure if it helps but I followed [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159198/47538) approach and got it to work in my machine.

Comment: @HaukeLaging If I read the "Setting guest network" document for KVM, then "Public Bridge" seems to be the set-up I need: http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Networking#public_bridge In other words, just as you said, VMs shall be able to communicate with each other and with outside world. So I need to create a bridge(br0), add one of the physical interfaces(eth0 in my case) into this bridge, create a tun device(tun0) and add it to this very same bridge br0. So I guess I need to create the VMs with virt-install using "--network bridge:tun0" option?

Comment: If you need only 2 vms then maybe a separate manager layer like `virsh/virt-install` is a bit much. Abstracting like that will only remove you - and your understanding of what makes it tick - from the whole process. This makes sense when talking about spawning vms programatically in great number - but if you just want to launch two vms occasionally then you'd probably get a better feel for how its done in `man qemu`.

Comment: @mikeserv I see. Am I correct that `virtsh/virt-install` tools control the `libvirt0` library which in turn is able to control the `qemu/qemu-kvm`? I guess `libvirt0` doesn't call the `qemu/qemu-kvm` utilities directly, but uses some sort of API provided by `qemu/qemu-kvm`?

Comment: `qemu-kvm` isnt a thing anymore - for a while it was the kernel support was getting baked-in to project, but its just `qemu` now. And yeah - those tools are indirect layers atop it. You can just call `qemu` from the cmdline. Check its `man` pages. Its easy.

Answer (score 1):

I have never used `virt-install`, I always use `virsh define file.xml`. But a look at the man page tells me that `--network bridge:tun0` is wrong. You need `--network=bridge=br0`.

I am not a `libvirt`/`qemu` expert thus I don't know whether you can create a `tun` device and make `libvirt` use it. Usually virtual interfaces are created dynamically when a VM is started and get connected to the bridge (and/or network).

In `libvirt`'s XML it looks like this:

```
<interface type='bridge'>
  <mac address='52:54:00:42:c4:c8'/>
  <source bridge='br0'/>
  <model type='virtio'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
```